# What does this expression この流れなら私だろ！ means in this context? [Manga]

Tags: meaning, manga, conversations

Context: a character (messenger-G1) is suspecting the person who she's talking to right now, is just a double and not the real (A-san) Leader of MC team. They're in a meeting, and G1 thinks a leader should be a strong person with longer hair than G2 (Dragon Ball reference ?), while A-san is timid and shy

> G1: …本当はどっちがA-san (leader)？
>
> A-san: はい？
>
> G1: 私みたいな怪しい使者を前に、警戒するのはわかるけどね。面会に堂々と影武者を出すのは、さすがに失礼じゃない？書状が本物だって確認もしたよね
>
> A-san: あ、あはは…
>
> MC's thought: ああ……そういう事かー。
>
> G2 (A-san friend): A-sanはまだまだ風格が足りないしなぁ
>
> G1:って事は、そっちの髪が長いの、あんたがA-sanか！
>
> G2: 私じゃないのかよ！**この流れなら私だろ！>> I don't understand this line**
>
> G1: …いや、あんたより髪が長いのの方が強そうだなって思って
>
> G2: うぅ……これでも、A-sanよりだいぶ偉いんだぞ、私…(G2 is city governor and she has a higher position than A-san)
>
> G3: 失礼な奴だな。私はAさま……A-sanではない
> (bodyguard of A-san, who has longer hair than G2,she don't want to address A-san with her real name so she changed her way of speaking)

Appreciate if someone help me understand the meaning of **"この流れなら私だろ"** here.

Answer (score 2):

Literally, it means ***With this course** of conversation, it should be **me** that you think is A-san*.

(Presumably) with 風格がたりない, G2 implicitly suggested that s/he is superior to A-san, which (G2 assumed) would increase the chance of G2 being taken as the leader. So G2 expected G1 to think that s/he is the leader. Then G1 directed ってことは... to G3 (again, presumably), which contradicted G2's expectation, whence この流れなら私だろ！.